# How can i get `accessConfig.getNatIP` of GCP `ManagedInstance` with java API?

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

I have this code to get the external ip of instances in GCP project

```
  private static void printInstances(Compute compute, String projectId) throws IOException {
        final Compute.Instances.List instances = compute.instances().list(projectId, zoneName);

        final InstanceList           list      = instances.execute();

        if ( list.getItems() == null ) {
            System.out.println("No instances found. Sign in to the Google APIs Console and create an instance at: code.google.com/apis/console");
        } else {
            for ( final Instance instance : list.getItems() ) {
                //System.out.println(instance.toPrettyString());
                System.out.println("------------- " + instance.getName() + " (" + instance.getId() + ")");

                final List<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = instance.getNetworkInterfaces();
                for ( final NetworkInterface networkInterface : networkInterfaces ) {
                    String extIP = null;

                    final List<AccessConfig> accessConfigs = networkInterface.getAccessConfigs();
                    for ( final AccessConfig accessConfig : accessConfigs ) {  // More than one?
                        extIP = accessConfig.getNatIP();
                    }

                    System.out.println("    Private=[" + networkInterface.getNetworkIP() + "]    Public=[" + extIP + "]");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get the same (meaning `accessConfig.getNatIP`) form instance of GCP `ManagedInstance`.

Like this:

```
Compute.InstanceGroupManagers.ListManagedInstances listInstances =
                    compute.instanceGroupManagers().listManagedInstances(projectId, zoneName, groupName);
            List<ManagedInstance> list =  listInstances.execute().getManagedInstances();
```

But I have found no way to get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Compute.InstanceGroupManagers.ListManagedInstances` contains the URLs of the instances. Then use [instances.get](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instances/get) API to get the external IP in the instance.